# Getting values of a column, depending values of another column

Tags: sql

I want to take all the data, (that matches from "name" column) from "barcode" column. Like this:

```
SELECT barcode FROM table1 where name like 'abc%'
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: "(that matches from "name" column) from "barcode" column." didn't get it

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: First excuse my close expression. I have a table that first column of it is "barcode" which is also my primary key. And one column named e.g."Category". Category values taken by combobox and e.g. like:"A, B, C, D". Now I want to put barcode values in another combobox but not all of them only the ones with "Category A". How can I do that? Note: I am using "datareader" for this...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "DBMS"? Like I said I am a beginner of programming. But it looks like RDBMS or maybe MSSQL...

Answer (score 0):

if you mean get barcode based on selected category value, you need to pass the selected value as SqlParameter. ex. in your OnCategoryChanged function,

```
    string queryString =
        "SELECT barcode FROM table1 where category=@category;";

    using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var cmd =  new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
        connection.Open();

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       ...

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Comment: A quality answer should include an explanation of *why* it works.

Comment: No. First excuse my close expression. I have a table that first column of it is "barcode" which is also my primary key. And one column named e.g."Category". Category values taken by combobox and e.g. like:"A, B, C, D". Now I want to put barcode values in another combobox but not all of them only the ones with "Category A". How can I do that? Note: I am using "datareader" for this...

Comment: Well category has been chosen before and already in the table. Now I want to add a new selection for user. User shall choose a "mother barcode" from where, for example, the rows that has category "A". After I get a selection I will raise that choosen "mother barcode" number and write another barcode for that entry.

Comment: Actually the code that you've kindly sent last, might work for me because I am taking values of Category from another Combobox and I can use it also to put the values to the "mother barcode" combox. But I couldn't apply it. I added " while (reader.Read());  { combobox6. Items.Add (reader [0].tostring ()); }" to your code but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

If anyone would be so kind to send, I am still waiting for an answer. Considering my comments above and below. Thank you...